# Self-Modifying MIPS Code

Tags: mips, self-modifying

I'm trying to write a program in MIPS that continuously prompts for two integers and prints the sum until the sum is 0. The trick is that if the sum is 13, I need to call a method to change the assembled MIPS code so that

```
add $t2, $t0, $t1
```

becomes

```
and $t2, $t0, $t1
```

and all subsequent runs of the loop use the and instruction.

I have the summation loop working so that when 13 is the sum the method instMod is called which I want to modify the instruction. Unfortunately, I have no idea where to start and can't find any examples of this online. I assume I need to somehow get the hex code of the add out of the assembled code and replace it with the hex code for the and but I do not know how to do that or if that is the right course of action to take.

```
# Nick Gilbert
# MIPS Program to demonstrate self-modifying code

.data
num1Prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter num1: "
num2Prompt:     .asciiz     "Enter num2: "
num1:           .word       0
num2:           .word       0
addOut:         .asciiz     "ADD: "
andOut:         .asciiz     "AND: "

.text
main:
sumLoop:
    la $a0, num1Prompt  #Asking user for num1
    li $v0, 4       #Call code to print string
    syscall     

    li $v0, 5       #Call code to read an int
    syscall
    move $t0, $v0       #Moving read int to $t1

    la $a0, num2Prompt  #Asking user for num2
    li $v0, 4       #Call code to print string
    syscall

    li $v0, 5       #Call code to read an int
    syscall
    move $t1, $v0       #Moving read int to $t2

    add $t2, $t0, $t1   #Adding num1 and num2 together

    la $a0, addOut
    li $v0, 4
    syscall

    move $a0, $t2
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

    beq $t2, 13, instMod    #Calling method to modify add instruction if sum = 13
    bne $t2, 0, sumLoop #If result is not yet 0, ask for new sum

endSumLoop:
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

instMod: #Method to change add instruction to an and instruction
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a label at the instruction you want to replace, e.g:

```
instruction_to_be_replaced:
  add $t2, $t0, $t1   #Adding num1 and num2 together
```

then in your routine instMod

```
instMod: #Method to change add instruction to an and instruction
    lw $t1, instruction_to_replace
    sw $t1, instruction_to_be_replaced
    j sumLoop  # go back to your sumLooop

instruction_to_replace:
    and $t2, $t0, $t1
```

The code loads in temporary register `$t1` the contents of the instruction you want to replace, and then stores it in the location labelled `instruction_to_be_replaced`.

The "source" of the instruction goes labelled in instruction_to_replace.

To do this, you need to be able to write on the code section which I assume you have otherwise you would not be asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Assemble the instruction that you need to an object file
2. Extract the hexadecimal of the equivalent machine code
3. Place a label in front of the code you need to change
4. `mov` the hexidecimal from step 2 into the location from step 3 in your `instMod` section

For this to function the two instructions with operands must be of identical length.  If they are not, pad the original or the replacement with `nop` as appropriate.

Comment: MIPS is a RISC architecture, so all instructions are 4 bytes long.

Comment: I figured that'd be the best strategy, the issue is how do I programmatically extract the location from step 3

Comment: Assemble the code and check what the offset is for that instruction in the compiled code...  objdump -d